# How to use ssh with command containing regex?

Tags: regex, bash, ssh

for example, I have a directory : /full/path/to/your/dir  which contains below files:

```
$ls /full/path/to/your/dir 
/full/path/to/your/dir/test.1.log.gz
/full/path/to/your/dir/test.2.log.gz
/full/path/to/your/dir/test.3.log.gz
```

if I run the cmd directly on the target host, it will print result without error:

```
$ls /full/path/to/your/dir/test.!(3).log*
/full/path/to/your/dir/test.1.log.gz
/full/path/to/your/dir/test.2.log.gz
```

but if i run on another host via ssh to the target host for execution, like:

```
$ssh myself@hostname "ls /full/path/to/your/dir/test.!(3).log*"
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `ls /full/path/to/your/dir/test.!(3).log*'
```

Also, I tried with below:

```
$ssh myself@hostname "ls /full/path/to/your/dir/test.'!(3)'.log*"
ls: /full/path/to/your/dir/test.!(3).log*:  No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help to tell how to correct the cmd ?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use extended pattern matching features which must be enabled first see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) That can be enable by `shopt -s extglob`

Comment: still not working with  $ssh myself@hostname "shopt -s extglob; ls /full/path/to/your/dir/test.'!(3)'.log*"

Comment: What if you delete single quotes around !(3)  $ssh myself@hostname "shopt -s extglob; ls /full/path/to/your/dir/test.!(3).log*"

Comment: I got why:1)if use "" to wrap around the commands,local shell will do path expansion.But files exist on remote,so should use ' ';2)the 2 commands will be evaluated first as one line before execution,hence extglob doesn't take effect when remote shell is doing globbing for ls, it can't recognize!().A trick can be used here is:$ssh myself@hostname 'shopt -s extglob; ls /full/path/to/your/dir/\`echo test.!(3).log*\`', then the globbing will be postponed until execution.You could have a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103058/exclude-characters-for-scp-filepattern) as well.

Answer (score -1):

what you can do is :

```
ssh myself@hostname 'ls | grep -v test\.\(3\)\.log$'
```

Comment: This regular expression is not equivalent to the original pattern. For instance, it would allow any file names which don't start with `test`, as long as it doesn't end in `3.log`.

Comment: then the user can change the regex according to his requirement. anyways i ll change it for the moment